# Unable disable or suppress the Hive Registration log

Tags: apache-spark, java-8, hive, log4j

In application, created a log file to write the log info and log error messages  But in log file, there are some unwanted Hive INFO logs are written

Sample log

```
INFO  Hive:234 - Registering function rank com citi oprisk andes udf Rank
```

Help me to remove or filter or disable from log file log4j properties

Using Spark 2 3 1 with hive and java 8

Want to write only application logs  should not print unwanted logs

```
INFO  Hive:234 - Registering function rank com citi oprisk andes udf Rank
2019-10-25 08:20:16 INFO  Hive:234 - Registering function udf1 com citi oprisk andes udf UDF1
2019-10-25 08:20:16 INFO  Hive:234 - Registering function rank1 com citi oprisk andes udf Rank1

Logger getLogger("org") setLevel(Level OFF);
Logger getLogger("akka") setLevel(Level OFF);
Logger getLogger("org apache spark") setLevel(Level OFF);
Logger getLogger("org apache hadoop hive") setLevel(Level OFF);
Logger getLogger("org apache") setLevel(Level OFF);
```

Comment: Any solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

I am running spark-sql_2.12 3.0.0 in local mode and seeing hundreds of such INFO logs like below during spark.sql(query):

```
2020-08-20 19:02:37,722 INFO  org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive Registering function date_diff brickhouse.udf.date.DayDiffUDF
2020-08-20 19:02:37,725 INFO  org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive Registering function add_iso_period brickhouse.udf.date.AddISOPeriodUDF
```

Attempt to setLevel to be Level.WARN of the related logger does not help.

```
org.apache.log4j.Logger.getLogger("org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive").setLevel(Level.WARN);
org.apache.log4j.Logger.getLogger("org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore").setLevel(Level.WARN);
```

In a contrast, such customization in code works for most other loggers. For example:

```
org.apache.log4j.Logger.getLogger("org.apache.spark").setLevel(Level.ERROR);
```

Eager to know how to suppress these Hive INFO logs.

Answer (score 0):

The following code works!

```
org.apache.log4j.Logger.getLogger("hive.ql.metadata.Hive").setLevel(Level.WARN);
```

The name "hive.ql.metadata.Hive" is used because the logger in Hive.java is created as below:

static final private Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger("hive.ql.metadata.Hive");

Answer (score 0):

for me, the following configuration suppress hive logs

```
Logger.getLogger("org.apache.spark").setLevel(Level.WARN)
Logger.getLogger("org.apache.hadoop").setLevel(Level.WARN)
Logger.getLogger("org.spark-project.hive").setLevel(Level.WARN)
```